# MySQL: assertion failure and then MySQL crash in file fut0lst.ic on starting the database

Tags: mysql

When restarting an existing MySQL database I am getting the following assertion failure and subsequent crash of MySQL. I have detailed my investigations into this below. I would be grateful if anyone has a suggested procedure to deal with this. One option I could do if dump out the data from affected table, drop the table, restart the database, then re-import the table data back into the database, however I am not sure at the moment which table(s) and whether this is the best route for dealing with this issue.

When I initially try to re-start the database I get the following (from mysqld.err):

```
151114 11:31:21 [Warning] No argument was provided to --log-bin, and --log-bin-index was not used; so replication may break when this MySQL server acts as a master and has his hostname changed!! Please use '--log-bin=mysqld-bin' to avoid this problem.
151114 11:31:21 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151114 11:31:21 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
151114 11:31:21 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
151114 11:31:21 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
151114 11:31:21 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 160.0M
151114 11:31:21 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
151114 11:31:21 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 36471217527
151114 11:31:21  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 36471230445
InnoDB: Transaction 3BCDD91AB was in the XA prepared state.
InnoDB: 1 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
InnoDB: in total 0 row operations to undo
InnoDB: Trx id counter is 3BCDD9300
151114 11:31:24  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 4560, file name ./mysqld-bin.000085
InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of uncommitted transactions
151114 11:31:25  InnoDB: Rollback of non-prepared transactions completed
151114 11:31:25  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
151114 11:31:26 InnoDB: 5.5.40 started; log sequence number 36471230445
151114 11:31:26 [Note] Recovering after a crash using mysqld-bin
151114 11:31:26 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
151114 11:31:26  InnoDB: Starting recovery for XA transactions...
151114 11:31:26  InnoDB: Transaction 3BCDD91AB in prepared state after recovery
151114 11:31:26  InnoDB: Transaction contains changes to 1 rows
151114 11:31:26  InnoDB: 1 transactions in prepared state after recovery
151114 11:31:26 [Note] Found 1 prepared transaction(s) in InnoDB
151114 11:31:26  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140429447350080 in file fut0lst.ic line 83
InnoDB: Failing assertion: addr.page == FIL_NULL || addr.boffset >= FIL_PAGE_DATA
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
11:31:26 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 134092 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x29)[0x76b1d9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x35c)[0x66e79c]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x11250)[0x7fb846d02250]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x7fb845900795]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x148)[0x7fb845901c18]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x5185a0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x86006e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x7ec726]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x800399]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x7f8a3e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x7f9bc5]    
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x7fadd4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x7b06f9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x66fe8b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24plugin_foreach_with_maskP3THDPFcS0_P13st_plugin_intPvEijS3_+0x145)[0x59bbb5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10ha_recoverP7st_hash+0x89)[0x6714e9]            /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN13MYSQL_BIN_LOG7recoverEP11st_io_cacheP28Format_description_log_event+0xe3)[0x6eab03]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN13MYSQL_BIN_LOG4openEPKc+0x3ff)[0x6eb51f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x52f7c9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x369)[0x52ff99]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7fb8458ecdb5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x528105]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

I have also run:

```
myisamchk --force */*.MYI
```

and this gives one table with:

```
myisamchk: warning: 8 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
```

and another with:

```
myisamchk: warning: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly
```

and another with:

```
Data records:       1   Deleted blocks:      27
```

The database can be restarted with innodb_force_recovery set to 3. With the database restarted I have run the following on it:

```
mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;

+----+-------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
| Id | User  | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State | Info                  |
+----+-------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
|  3 | root  | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | NULL  | SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST |
|  9 | MAIN  | localhost | beta | Sleep   |    4 |       | NULL                  |
| 10 | MAIN  | localhost | beta | Sleep   |    4 |       | NULL                  |
+----+-------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+





mysql> show engine innodb status\G

*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Type: InnoDB
  Name: 
Status: 
=====================================
151116 16:13:00 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 60 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 0 1_second, 0 sleeps, 0 10_second, 0  background, 0 flush
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 0
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 22, signal count 20
Mutex spin waits 23, rounds 571, OS waits 17
RW-shared spins 2, rounds 60, OS waits 2
RW-excl spins 3, rounds 90, OS waits 3
Spin rounds per wait: 24.83 mutex, 30.00 RW-shared, 30.00 RW-excl
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 3BCDD956F
Purge done for trx's n:o (less than) 0 undo n:o (less than) 0
History list length 2431
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 3BCDD9562, not started
MySQL thread id 6, OS thread handle 0x7fec180a8700, query id 628 localhost MAIN
---TRANSACTION 3BCDD956E, not started
MySQL thread id 4, OS thread handle 0x7fec1812a700, query id 640 localhost MAIN
---TRANSACTION 0, not started
MySQL thread id 3, OS thread handle 0x7fec1816b700, query id 641 localhost root
show engine innodb status
---TRANSACTION 3BCDD91AB, ACTIVE 351 sec recovered trx
1 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0],
ibuf aio reads: 0, log i/o's: 0, sync i/o's: 0
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
1131 OS file reads, 3 OS file writes, 3 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.00 writes/s, 0.00 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 215, seg size 217, 0 merges
merged operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 332147, node heap has 2 buffer(s)
47.70 hash searches/s, 28.50 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 36471230491
Log flushed up to   36471230445
Last checkpoint at  36471217527
0 pending log writes, 0 pending chkp writes
8 log i/o's done, 0.00 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 171704320; in additional pool allocated 0
Dictionary memory allocated 105878
Buffer pool size   10240
Free buffers       9293
Database pages     945
Old database pages 368
Modified db pages  69
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 945, created 0, written 0
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 945, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
1 read views open inside InnoDB
Main thread process no. 28337, id 140651961026304, state: waiting for server activity
Number of rows inserted 0, updated 0, deleted 0, read 16977
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 65.40 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

Then when I try to shutdown the database, it fails to shutdown and I get the following in the mysqld.err (I have let this run for a number of hours):

```
151115  0:07:21  InnoDB: Waiting for 1 active transactions to finish
```

*Apologises for the formating, StackOverflow has decided that what I am writing is all MySQL code!*

Comment: Does the information here seem relevant? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78115/shut-down-mysql-during-innodb-rollback-after-crash